# Acceptable Level of Snarkiness

Tags: discussion

I know. **Worldbuilders are nice**. Nice, calm, gentle people. All business (of writing) all the time. At least in public.

Nonetheless (I guess there's a reason why I'm asking this while saint-like Monica Cellio's away for the day), some questions/answers are just so off-the-wall silly (no specific examples, please) that a tiny teeensy smidgen of snark *totally, absolutely, necessarily must be employed*.

So, any suggestions?

EDIT: I have been made to see the light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does "Snark" actually achieve?

It might give you a smug feeling of having put someone down but what good has it actually done for anyone really?

If people are misguided then telling them so is fine. For example I've seen quite a few scientific fallacies corrected.

Just because someone may be lacking in knowledge of a certain area doesn't mean we should be nasty to them though. :)

Comment: Fine, I'll keep being nice.